# Trying to open Explorer View with Internet Explorer 11

Tags: sharepoint-designer, sharepoint-online, internet-explorer, open-with-explorer, explorer

I am currently trying to open Explorer View on SharePoint so that I can move documents into folders.

I un-installed all the updates on my Internet Explorer so that I had Internet Explorer 9 on my laptop. but it turned out to be Internet 9 64-bit. Then once I tried to get onto the Internet the browser just crashed and wouldn't load. I have now updated my version back to IE 11.

Is there anything else which can help to resolve this issue so I can open in Explorer View?

Comment: sharepoint 2010 or 2013?

Comment: Its the Online Microsoft office SharePoint 2013

Comment: Did you try http://community.office365.com/en-us/f/154/t/177482.aspx

Comment: I downloaded that yesterday and never seemed to get anywhere with it, once I have downloaded do I just try and gain access to explorer view then or is there something else I need to do?

Comment: did you try the compatibility Mode( also called EMIE-enterprise mode)?

Comment: No? I've never heard of that before.

Comment: check this blog how to enable it...http://blogs.technet.com/b/canitpro/archive/2014/04/16/windows-8-1-tips-how-to-enable-enterprise-mode-in-internet-explorer-11.aspx

Comment: Have tried that, it still doesn't work. When I hover over the open with explorer area, I get a message which states that this control is currently disabled and it is greyed out
And my laptop is Windows 7